# Sample project to automate Mobile app using geb with appium

Tags: appium, geb

I am trying to automate mobile app using Geb with appium. Just want to know how to use it through page objects. I set the capabilities but I am confused at getBrowser(). Do we have to use getBrowser() since its an native app. Any help would be appreciated @Durgesh

Answer (score 0):

`geb.Browser` class is the entrypoint for Geb and you will be using it one way or another if you are using Geb. The `Browser` class is more less a facade over `WebDriver` API which you would be using when using Appium anyway. While referencing `browser` in Appium tests for native mobile apps might feel misleading there is essentially nothing wrong with it. It's down to the fact that Appium is piggybacking on an API designed for automating browsers while it itself is about automating native apps.